# Entity Framework - incorrect query

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework

Всем привет

У меня есть база данных и правильный запрос в ней:

```
select ledgeraccounttypeid, dateeffective, sum(amount) from ledgertransaction
where ledgeraccounttypeid in (2) and dateeffective = '2020-12-06' 
group by ledgeraccounttypeid, dateeffective
```

Я пытаюсь сделать это с помощью EF, но я не уверен, что верно это делаю, я создал два запроса, можете подсказать какой из них верный и как его лучше поправить:

1)

```
var roomRevenueQuery = _reportsDbContext.LedgerTransactions.AsNoTracking().
                Where(x => x.LedgerAccountTypeId.Equals(reportRequest.Input.RoomChargeIds) &&
                      x.DateEffective == turnedDate).GroupBy(x => x.LedgerAccountTypeId)
```

2. 

```
var roomRevenueQuery = _reportsDbContext.LedgerTransactions.AsNoTracking().
                    Select(x => new LedgerTransaction
                    {
                        LedgerAccountTypeId = x.???,
                        DateEffective = turnedDate,
                        Amount = x.???
                    }).ToList();
```

Первый запрос кажется правильным, однако на выходе метода мне нужно вернуть объект как во втором методе, тут и возникают проблемы

3)

```
var roomRevenueQuery = _reportsDbContext.LedgerTransactions.AsNoTracking()
               .Where(x => x.LedgerAccountTypeId.Equals(reportRequest.Input.RoomChargeIds) &&
                      x.DateEffective == turnedDate)
               .GroupBy(x => x.LedgerAccountTypeId)
               .Select(s => new LedgerTransaction
               {
                   LedgerAccountTypeId = s.Key,
                   DateEffective = turnedDate,
                   Amount = s.Sum(x=>x.Amount),
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Amount это значение в группе с ключом (ledgeraccounttypeid, dateeffective)?

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы. Исходя из ledgeraccounttypeid, dateeffective будет выдаваться значение amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом коде запрос заканчивается `GroupBy()` - это "отложенный" метод, так что для получения объекта вам надо добавить в конец "немедленный" метод, вызывающий перечислитель, т.е. `ToList()`, `ToArray()`, ... см [классификацию LINQ-методов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution).

Попробуйте так

```
class ledgertransaction // Строка таблицы в БД.
{
    public int ledgeraccounttypeid;
    public DateTime dateeffective;
    public int AbstractValue;
}

class LedgerTransaction
{
    public int ledgeraccounttypeid;
    public DateTime dateeffective;
    public int Amount; // of AbstractValue.
}
```

Имитирую таблицу в БД.

```
// Таблица.
List<ledgertransaction> LedgerTransactions = new List<ledgertransaction>
{
    new ledgertransaction
    {
        ledgeraccounttypeid = 1,
        dateeffective = DateTime.Now,
        AbstractValue = 10
    },
    new ledgertransaction // *
    {
        ledgeraccounttypeid = 2,
        dateeffective = DateTime.Now,
        AbstractValue = 20
    },
    new ledgertransaction // *
    {
        ledgeraccounttypeid = 2,
        dateeffective = DateTime.Now,
        AbstractValue = 30
    },
    new ledgertransaction // *
    {
        ledgeraccounttypeid = 3,
        dateeffective = DateTime.Now,
        AbstractValue = 30
    },
    new ledgertransaction
    {
        ledgeraccounttypeid = 3,
        dateeffective = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
        AbstractValue = 40
    },
};
```

Выбираю параметры для `WHERE`. Для наглядности беру не одну двойку, а 2 и 3.

```
DateTime searchDt = DateTime.Now;
int[] searchIds = { 2, 3 };
```

Делаю выборку (как в комментарии автора).

```
List<LedgerTransaction> result = /* _reportsDbContext. */LedgerTransactions
    .Where(x => searchIds.Any(y => y == x.ledgeraccounttypeid) && x.dateeffective == searchDt)
    .GroupBy(
        x => new { id = x.ledgeraccounttypeid, date = x.dateeffective },
        y => y.AbstractValue,
        (key, value) => new LedgerTransaction
        {
            ledgeraccounttypeid = key.id,
            dateeffective = key.date,
            Amount = value.Count() // Я не знаю что именно надо в значение.
        })
    .ToList();
```

Получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Найденные элементы отмечены комментарием со "*" в коде List LedgerTransactions.

**Если работает как надо, то проверьте этот LINQ-запрос на своей БД, внеся необходимые изменения для вашей задачи.**

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ ! 
Можете ещё подсказать, а в чем разница между тем что вы написали и "3" блоком кода. Я его добавил в свой вопрос

Comment: Имеется в виду разница между Equals() и Any()?

Comment: @КириллФилободченко "in(2)" в вопросе читается как "который в множестве {2}, с учетом этого и решал задачу.

Comment: Нет, я имею ввиду что сделал select и там создал объект, а в вашем решении объект создаётся в groupby

Comment: В GroupBy() можно определить возвращаемый этим методом результат пользовательского типа так же, как и в Select(). Это какбы GroupBy() с Select() внутренним... . По сути разница только в стиле наптсания запроса.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваши ответы, отличного дня!